# Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to build a simple bar chart with some financial data in json format.

I am having this strange error popup when I try to use my parsed time. When I console log it shows the data to be parsed ok - it doesn't return null or anything.

```
d3.v3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined
    at H (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at SVGTextElement.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at SVGTextElement.arguments.length.each.function.n.textContent (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at d3.v3.min.js:3
    at Y (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at Array.Co.each (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at Array.Co.text (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (d3.v3.min.js:5)
    at d3.v3.min.js:3
    at Y (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

Its hard to troubleshoot this as I cannot understand which part of my code is responsible for causing this problem because it points toward d3.v3.min.js. I assume that the problem is in d3.extent as I used it to replace d3.max for the x-axis.

This is the code that gives the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>

    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S.%L").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S.%L"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/cba0e652b7fd9349604cf45ced75fbf9/raw/3f824e76c38479a1a327abbb5c85a5962fec6f21/schudata.json", function(error, data) {

    data["bboList"].forEach(function(d) {
        d.timeStr = parseDate(d.timeStr);
        d.value = +d.ask;
        console.log(d.timeStr)
    });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timeStr; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.timeStr); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});

</script>

</body>
```

P.S.

There is another issue which is outside the bounds of this question, but needs to be included.

In order to get the bars to render also replaced

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
```

with

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
```

and changing the width for the bars to a fixed value.

Comment: Your source data has dates in two different date formats. timeStr = `09:37:12.680` works fine with your parseDate, however where the time is in UNIX timestamp format, it  doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume that the problem is in d3.extent...

Yes, you are correct, and the explanation is simple: `d3.extent` accepts an **array** as the first argument. However, your `data` is not an array, but an **object** with two properties (each one having one array).

Thus, you should select one of them to set your domains (and your bar's data as well):

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data["bboList"], function(d) {
    return d.timeStr;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data["bboList"], function(d) {
    return d.value;
})]);
```

Here is your working code:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S.%L").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S.%L"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/cba0e652b7fd9349604cf45ced75fbf9/raw/3f824e76c38479a1a327abbb5c85a5962fec6f21/schudata.json", function(error, data) {

    data["bboList"].forEach(function(d) {
        d.timeStr = parseDate(d.timeStr);
        d.value = +d.ask;
    });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data["bboList"], function(d) { return d.timeStr; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data["bboList"], function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data["bboList"])
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.timeStr); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});
```

```css
path, line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Have in mind that I'm only answering your question (*"Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined"*). You still have some problems drawing those bars.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can see it is trying to plot the rectangles on top of each other.